Create WebSocket Connection in Chrome Extension Content Script Error
According to the Chrome docs, content scripts should be able to create web socket connections:

WebSockets work in a variety of extension components, be it content scripts...

I tested this out with a simple example below, and it did not work. What am I doing wrong?
Reproducible Steps
Setup Websocket

Install websocket library
npm init -y
npm install ws



Create a WebSocket Server (server.js):
const WebSocket = require('ws');

const server = new WebSocket.Server({ port: 8000 });

server.on('connection', (socket) => {
  console.log('Client connected');

  socket.on('message', (message) => {
    console.log('Received:', message);
  });

  socket.send('Hello from server');

  socket.on('close', () => {
    console.log('Client disconnected');
  });
});

console.log('WebSocket server is running on ws://localhost:8000');



Run the WebSocket Server:
node server.js




Setup Chrome Extension

File Structure:
my-chrome-extension/
│
├── manifest.json
├── content.js
└── icon.png  (your icon file)



manifest.json:
{
  "manifest_version": 3,
  "name": "WebSocket Extension",
  "version": "1.0",
  "description": "A simple Chrome extension to connect to a WebSocket server.",
  "permissions": [
    "activeTab"
  ],
  "background": {
    "service_worker": "background.js"
  },
  "icons": {
    "48": "icon.png"
  ],
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["<all_urls>"],
      "js": ["content.js"]
    }
  ]
}



content.js:
// Create a WebSocket connection to ws://localhost:8000
const socket = new WebSocket('ws://localhost:8000');

socket.addEventListener('open', () => {
  console.log('WebSocket connection established');
});

socket.addEventListener('message', (event) => {
  console.log('Message from server:', event.data);
});

socket.addEventListener('close', () => {
  console.log('WebSocket connection closed');
});

socket.addEventListener('error', (error) => {
  console.error('WebSocket error:', error);
});



Load the Extension:

Go to chrome://extensions/ in Chrome.

Enable "Developer mode."

Click "Load unpacked" and select the extension folder.



Go to any webpage


Outcome
The WebSocket connection is not established; no logs in the web socket server.
I get the below error in the web console:
WebSocket connection to 'ws://localhost:8000/' failed

WebSocket error: *Event {isTrusted: true, type: 'error', target: WebSocket, currentTarget: WebSocket, eventPhase: 2, …}*

Is this a content issue on the Chrome Extension Docs? Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Chrome blocks cross-origin requests in content scripts since a few years ago. Do it inside background.js.
